# Left click causes 'rename active item' in viewport and scene collection

Tags: settings, mouse

I am having trouble in using left click in the viewport. Left click causes the **rename** dialog to open and hence I cannot select and deselect any object. It is very annoying as the left click is not working as we normally expect it to.
[image: LeftClickInViewport]

Same issue is seen if I try to click anything under Scene Collection.

I checked online for a related solution but didn't find any.
My setting in Edit -> Preferences -> Keymap -> Select with Mouse Button is set to "Left". But yet I am seeing this issue.
[image: KeymapSettings]

I searched if there are any other settings to assign this kind of functionality for a type of mouse click, but I cannot find any.

I am using Blender 3.2.2 version on Windows 11. On Windows 10 too I had the same issue and had re-installed too. Issue is seen irrespective of using a mouse or the laptop touchpad.
Please help!

Comment: Any particular reason you're using such an old Blender version? 3.3.6 is the current LTS version, 3.5.1 is the current version and 3.6 LTS is due at the end of this month (June).

Comment: @JohnEason I am taking a course which uses 3.2. So to follow it up, I was using 3.2 version. But I got the solution from the community.

Answer (score 0):

I got this solution from other Blender users.

Press F4 -> preferences -> click menu icon (indicated by 3 lines at the bottom left) -> load factory preferences.
Click on save preferences.

OR

Edit -> Preferences -> Keymap -> Window -> search for Rename active item -> click Left Click and assign it to any other shortcut.